# Why is an NAA flag disputed while the majority of reviewers agreed to delete the post?

Tags: discussion, support

There is something in the review process which I do not understand.

I raised an NAA flag which was disputed. It's not that I want to insist on deletion (and therefore I do not link to the post and/or review). However, I wonder how this is possible as the majority of reviewers agreed it should be deleted:

[image: result]

It seems that 'Recommend Deletion' does not really count here, is that right? I assume that this may be because the reviewers had not the privilege to vote to delete. However they do have the power to prevent deletion by clicking 'Looks OK'? Isn't that a biased review process? And what is 'Recommend Deletion' good for then?

EDIT:

As it seems to be important: Reputations were

- Recommend Deletion: 2161, 2630, 4151
- Looks OK: 7972, 2409, 26004
- Delete:25596, 153126

Comment: Because the 'recommendations' (from people without the delete privilege) don't count when 3 people with more reputation vote 'looks OK'.

Comment: More details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/164200).

Comment: The review system failed here. All three "Looks OK" voters have little to no discernible knowledge about C#, whereas the rest of the voters either hold a C# tag badge or have a significant amount of reputation (indicating knowledge of how SO is supposed to work). The answer should have been deleted because it simply does not answer the question—even though I agree with its advice! (It is now deleted.)

Comment: @CodyGray: it did not. The post gets a final pass through the moderator queue. I certainly would have deleted it too had I found it there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [central FAQ on reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work/161391#161391):

> If you haven't earned the [trusted user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you'll be offered a **Recommend Deletion** option instead - this will prioritize the review task for others who *can* vote to delete, and if a sufficient number of reviewers all recommend deletion (as of March 2014, the number is six) it can cause the post to be either deleted (if the score is less than or equal to 0) or forwarded to moderators for further review.

So unless there are 6 *recommend deletion* votes, then the only effect recommending deletion has is to prioritise the review.

Without 6 such recommendations, it comes down to a vote between the *Looks OK* and *Delete* votes (the latter cast by users with the *Trusted user* privilege), and in this case *Looks OK* won.

However, posts like these, where the total number of *Deletion* votes (so including recommendations) outnumbers the *Looks OK* flags, are automatically flagged for diamond moderator attention with the *disputed low quality review (auto) (Controversial review: more delete votes than 'looks good')* flag. It's in our queue and a moderator will take a look at it, and give a final verdict.

Comment: Or, the community will just delete it. The Meta post brought enough attention to it for a third and final deletion vote from a trusted user.

Comment: I should also note that moderators and SE staff have done quite a bit of analysis for how these disputed reviews typically wind up. At first, I was skeptical that we'd see reasonable deletion reviews, so we got automatic flags on many of the disputed reviews. What I saw was that almost all of the disputed reviews were on content that shouldn't be deleted, so the safe option became to dispute these. The unanimous deletion reviews were almost always on things that did need to be deleted. The way the flags are handled by the system is shaped by how the community has performed in these reviews.

Comment: That's not to say that review is perfect. Every now and then, something will go wrong and further action may be required. However, the Low Quality Posts review has been pretty consistent in behavior, to the point where I think it's worth looking at lowering the number of unanimous delete votes required to delete a post in the queue.

Comment: @BradLarson in this particular corner case I see two delete votes and three recommendations and then think "just delete it already!". The existence of multiple recommendations should give the full delete votes more weight, IMO.

Comment: *" ... if a sufficient number of reviewers all recommend deletion (as of March 2014, the number is six)..."* - what a waste of resources. Reviewers are a scarce commodity.

Comment: @jww: It's being lowered to 4 for a month, see [Testing, testing... Let's test the low quality review queue for science!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342632)